# How to upload 10 images to server from iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, image, background-process

I am new to iPhone.

I have created an iPhone application. In this application, i have to give one option to upload more than one image to server. Suppose if the user closed the application also, it should upload all the images in background.

I don't know how to do this. Please suggest me to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Background mode doesn't allow that kind of process.

Save your images paths in NSUserDefault and restart it when the app restart

Comment: Could you please tell me, how the alarm kind of application is working ?

Comment: Alarm app use UILocalNotification http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html It's a cron like feature. You can't use that for background content downloading/uploading

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2277/_index.html explain that you can't do what you want.

Comment: This can be done using `-beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` on `UIApplication`. You get a maximum of 10 minutes to complete any operation before your process is killed.

Answer (score 0):

Image Save on NSUserDefaults

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1) forKey:@"image"];

Read From NSUserDefaults

NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"image"];

UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

Answer (score 0):

Check out the reference for `UIApplication`'s [`-beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW79).

Here's a basic example...

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // self.backgroundTask is a property on the app delegate.
    if (self.backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) // A background task is still in process. Bail early.
        return;

    __weak AppDelegate *weakSelf = self; // Create a weak reference to self to avoid retain cycles
    self.backgroundTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [application endBackgroundTask:weakSelf.backgroundTask];        
        weakSelf.backroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    }];

    dispatch_async((DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Kick off task to upload photos here.

        [application endBackgroundTask:weakSelf.backgroundTask];
        weakSelf.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```